# How to test TLS False Start feature

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, ssl, load-balancing, openssl

I am currently enabled both ALPN and forward secrecy for my server using aws network load balancer which support tls up to 1.2. And I would like to know how to validate/test that TSL False Start is enabled.

I am testing with openssl and catch the traffic using wireshack, but did not give me the expected result. Or the aws network load balancer does not support TLS false start.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Follow up, NLB do support false start features, yet,  you need to test with chrom or IE browers to do so. Curl does not support that.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ can test/verify what you need?

Comment: Thanks for quick response，I tested using the site you mentioned, it did not indicate whether it is supported or not.